# Can I use natbib in beamer, but omit the bibliography?

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, biblatex, natbib

Can I call references from my `.bib` file, but not put a huge bibliography at the end of my presentation? Or at least hide it in a bunch of slides that don't display?

I tend to think in terms of my `.bib` file handles and like the consistent formatting.

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31373/citations-with-no-bibliography-at-the-end/31378#31378

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is yet another reason to use [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) -- printing the bibliography is not mandatory.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame title}
Some text \autocite{A01}.
\end{frame}

% Optional: Prints bibliography 
% \begin{frame}{References}
% \printbibliography
% \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

(The `filecontents` environment is only used to include some external files directly into the example, so that it compiles. It is not necessary for the solution.)

Answer (score 17):

Use `<beamer:0>` to hide any slide from the presentation:

```
\begin{frame}<beamer:0>
    \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
    \bibliography{bibliography}
\end{frame}
```

This simple solution worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Wow. Thanks! I still haven't made the switch to biblatex (and likely won't) so this is handy.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this. Put in:

```
\usepackage{comment}
```

Process the file once including the full bibliography. Then run bibtex. Now put in:

```
\excludecomment{thebibliography}
```

Run (pdf)latex again, and the bibliography will not be printed (merely treated as a "comment"). Unfortunately, you'll need to remove this (or comment this out) the next time, and then re-add it in alternation to keep things in order, but if you wait until you have your final document ready and then put it in, you should be OK.

This basic idea is stolen from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3331/how-do-i-simply-typeset-a-bibliography-as-a-separate-pdf).

(Somewhat unrelated, I find that I need to manually define `\newblock` to get `natbib` working with `beamer`, e.g., `\newcommand{\newblock}{}`.)

Comment: Thanks! I think in this case the `biblatex` answer is best for me, but your's is good for my toolbox.

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1969/beamer-and-natbib for the natbib/beamer problem