# Citations with no bibliography at the end

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

How do you produce a document with citations (`\citep`, `\citet`) working properly in the paper but without a bibliography at the end?

I've come up with one solution that is bad because it breaks my `makefile`.

```
latex file.tex
bibtex file
# comment out \bibliography{} command
latex file.tex
```

Similarly, is there a way to produce the bibliography with no accompanying text?  Again, I've come up with a solution: fill an otherwise blank `.tex` file with `\nocite{}` commands.  However, this is a pain because I have to keep two files synced by hand (and regular expressions to search for `\citep{author1, author2}` can be a huge pain when there are pagebreaks...).

Comment: why are you commenting out the `\bibliography{}` command?  presumably you *do* have a `.bib` file, otherwise it makes no sense to have any `\cite` instructions. once bibtex has created a `.bbl` file from the `.bib` file, it doesn't matter whether the cite entries are put into the `.aux` file again.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your second request is easy: [use `\nocite{*}`](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-nocitestar.html). This will produce a full bibliography, regardless of which bibliography entries are actually cited.

Comment: This is a good idea only if your `.bib` file contains nothing *but* entries you want in your bibliography. I guess that's so for the OP but thought it worth mentioning for others. It would produce something ridiculous with a common database of entries, for example.

Answer (score 71):

Use the `\usepackage{bibentry}` and then instead of `\bibliography{}` use `\nobibliography{}`.

e.g.

```
\nobibliography{/Users/Thomas/Dropbox/bibliography.bib}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Thanks for your answer, we're looking forward to your future contributions to this Q&A.

Comment: It didn't work for me in beamer.

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you for sharing your answer!

Comment: \bibentry{label} outputs nothing for me. I'm not the only one for whom it is not working it seems: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422161/bibentry-no-output.

Answer (score 31):

You can define a savebox and put the `\bibliography` command inside the savebox.

Here is a small example:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{test,
author={Name},
title={TITLE},
year={2011},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\begin{document}
\cite{test}

\newsavebox\mytempbib
\savebox\mytempbib{\parbox{\textwidth}{\bibliography{test}}}

\end{document}
```

NOTE: If you are using `biblatex` you don't need such hacks.

**EDIT**

In relation to my answer I have a small question. What do you think about a small package which allows the user to print the bibliography or not?

Here my first try:

```
%% Copyright (C) 2011 by Marco Daniel
\ProvidesPackage{nobibprint}[2011/10/12 v0.1 nobibprint]
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\define@boolkey{nobibprint.sty}[nobib@]{hide}{}
\ExecuteOptionsX{hide=true}
\ProcessOptionsX
\newsavebox\nobib@tempbox
\ifnobib@hide
   \AtBeginDocument{%
     \let\nobib@bibliography@orig\bibliography
     \def\bibliography#1{%
        \savebox\nobib@tempbox{%
           \parbox{\linewidth}{%
              \nobib@bibliography@orig{#1}%
            }%
        }%
      }%
   }
\fi
\endinput
```

Now simple use:

```
\usepackage{nobibprint}
```

or:

```
\usepackage[hide=true]{nobibprint}%default
```

or

```
\usepackage[hide=false]{nobibprint}
```

Comment: I certainly like the idea of the package, and will give it a shot.  I don't think I understand saveboxes; will have to look those up.

Comment: Amazing, but I still had to add `\bibliographystyle{}` before `\bibliography{}`. Otherwise, this is magical.

Comment: Great. Just to be clear, the only thing that's needed is: \newsavebox\mytempbib
\savebox\mytempbib{\parbox{\textwidth}{\bibliography{test}}}

Answer (score 9):

If you put the `\bibliography` command in a file, say `bibcommand.tex` and in the main file you say

```
\documentclass{book}
...
%\includeonly{}
...

\begin{document}
<the document>

\include{bibcommand}

\end{document}
```

then a normal compilation will include the bibliography, but commenting out `\includeonly{}` will omit it.

You can also add the `\includeonly{}` from the shell

```
latex "\includeonly{}\input{filename}"
```

(where your main file is `filename.tex`) and this may be included in a `Makefile`, I believe.

Comment: So \includeonly{} forces the later \include command to be ignored?  And using "latex [some latexcommand] filename" prepends the latex command to the file?  Both very useful features, thanks.

Comment: @Sosi I'd like to acknowledge who first taught me this trick, but it was something I read in `comp.text.tex` several years ago.

Answer (score 7):

Simply use [biblatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) and its `natbib` compatibility option.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \citep{A01}.

% \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a foo.bbl file that you want to pull from (e.g. from another main document), a slight modification from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99726/how-tell-latex-to-use-existing-bbl-file-without-running-bibtex) works wonders:

```
\newsavebox\mytempbib
\savebox\mytempbib{\parbox{\textwidth}{\input{foo.bbl}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your first question: "How do you produce a document with citations (`\citep, \citet`) working properly in the paper but without a bibliography at the end?"

This maybe a dirty solution, but please try adding `\vspace*{-200in}` right before your `\bibliography{}` command. I think the whole references then go to somewhere too high to be seen.

Comment: This is really great solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your makefile can empty the *.bbl file.  If you want to use Konrad's suggestion to separately compile the bibliography, you can try the following (untested):

```
file.dvi: file.tex
        latex file
        bibtex file
        mv -f file.bbl references.bbl; touch file.bbl
        latex file
        latex references
```

where references.tex is the Latex file that invokes `\nocite{*}`.

Answer (score 0):

I used a sorta hack :)

[Compiling only a page range or page selection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96256/compiling-only-a-page-range-or-page-selection)

this gives info on page selection while making pdf ... I put a \newpage before bibliography and just didn't compile those pages ...