# Compile but don't print references

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Citations with no bibliography at the end](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31373/citations-with-no-bibliography-at-the-end)

I have a document with a very tight space restriction and I've found that it is easier to compact my references by copying them from a compiled PDF into the document. However this obviously gives two copies of the bibliography in the document. Is there any way in which to compile the references for a document, so that the citations are numbered correctly etc. but not actually print the references?

Answer (score 5):

run your document as usual and then run it *one time*
with a commented `%\blibliography{...}`

Comment: ...since this will still use the saved `.aux` file containing the correct references to produce the document. Compiling *twice* will use the updated (now void of `\bibitem`s) `.aux` resulting in undefined citations.

Comment: please read, what I wrote!

Comment: ...I did, and elaborated.

Comment: it is _obvious_ that I get no citations when running _twice_!

Comment: You provided an elegant and straight-forward solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
\makeatletter
\def\bibliography#1{%
   \if@filesw
   \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\bibdata{#1}}%
\fi}
\makeatother
```

Note that in latex.ltx this command is defined as

```
\def\bibliography#1{%
  \if@filesw
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\bibdata{#1}}%
  \fi
 \@input@{\jobname.bbl}}
```

This command writes the bibliography files to the .aux file, and the last line reads the .bbl file and inserts it at the point.  By redefining the command you keep the first part and get rid of the last one.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on your answer? Suggesting "Try this..." or "Here you go..." solutions provides little context and no justification as to the choice of your code.

Comment: <em>Would you care to elaborate on your answer? Suggesting "Try this..." or "Here you go..." solutions provides little context and no justification as to the choice of your cod</em><br> Surely