# How tell LaTeX to use existing bbl file without running bibtex?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

How can I tell LaTeX that it should use an existing bbl file `foo.bbl`, say, without running `bibtex`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

OK, I see, just use `\input{foo.bbl}`. The `bbl` file just contains the `bibitems` and thus can be included like any other content.

Comment: maybe `\InputIfFileExists{foo.bbl}` ?

Comment: This is a great solution for making the "References cited" file for an NSF grant proposal.

Comment: How to get citation numbers? Like [2].

Comment: This seems to be the best solution for arXiv manuscripts.

Answer (score 11):

LaTeX attempts to read a `.bbl` file when you use the `\bibliography` command. If the file does not exist, you get an empty bibliography. LaTeX doesn't 'know' if you run BibTeX, it only knows if a `.bbl` file exists. (You can make a `.bbl` file by hand, and it will work.)

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I meant. I have a `.bbl` file (created "somehow", let's say) and I want LaTeX to use it without biblatex coming into play.

Comment: Some systems (e.g. LaTeXtools for Sublime Text) automatically run `pdflatex`, `bibtex` and `pdflatex` again during a 'Build', so note that in this answer the idea is to NOT run `bibtex` as this creates a new .bbl file. This means any `\bibliography{foo}` will be ignored. If nothing else, you can use the CLI to just run `pdflatex` once, if your editor of choice runs `biblatex` by default. The good thing about this approach is that the source .tex file does not need to be modified.