# How can I use the reference citation numbers from the main document in an external document?

Tags: bibtex, back-referencing

I'm preparing a manuscript, and the appendices are supposed to be in a different file.  I'm using bibTeX to manage my references.

I would like to cite references in the appendices. Is there a way to pull the source number from the main document?

E.g., bibliography output in main document:

[1] a source

[2] another source

[3] extra source

External document:

```
And this is due to \cite{another_source_label}
```

should produce

"And this is due to [2]"

which would match the numbering in the main document.

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to use the same bibliography file but to "hide" the References list. This question seems to address this point: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31373/12921

Comment: Well, of course, to make sure you keep the same numbering, you should `\nocite{}` all your previously used references.

Comment: If I understand your question, is the easiest not to compile them as one document and split the resulting pdf afterwards?

Comment: @Aubrey Blumsohn The master template I'm using unfortunately has page numbers at the bottom, including the total page numbers.  I tried to adjust (stop) the page numbers using

    \pagenumbering{gobble}

but that didn't work because then the total number of pages was blank.    I know how to manually adjust page numbers in Beamer, but not in a LaTeX document...I'm using the LaTeX template from http://journals.plos.org/plosone/s/latex#loc-plos-template

Comment: @AlfredoHernández  Thank you!  That was exactly what I needed.  I wanted to pull exactly from a bbl file, so this modified command works perfectly. \newsavebox\mytempbib
\savebox\mytempbib{\parbox{\textwidth}{\input{growthFromTemplate.bbl}}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @AlfredoHernández for his answer.  Following [his suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31373/12921), with a slight modification I found from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99726/how-tell-latex-to-use-existing-bbl-file-without-running-bibtex), this command

```
\newsavebox\mytempbib
\savebox\mytempbib{\parbox{\textwidth}{\input{mainFile.bbl}}}
```

works perfectly.