# Using bibentry to insert reference in text and omit the list of references at the end

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am using `bibentry` package to insert references in the text of the document. This is a CV and the references are my own publications. I want to remove the bibliography listed at the end of the document. So far, I have had no success. Here is an example .tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}

\begin{document}

\nobibliography*

Some text here. My publications:
\begin{itemize}
\item \bibentry{pub1} 
\item \bibentry{pub2}
\end{itemize}

Some other text.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{my_pubs}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31373/citations-with-no-bibliography-at-the-end

Comment: @Closers Why would this question be a duplicate of the linked one?

Comment: I agree with @karlkoeller; the linked question *wants* a bibliography at the end whereas this one wants to *remove* it.

Comment: @karlkoeller, I added a comment to your solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

You are misusing the package `bibentry`.

When you DON'T want the bibliography to be printed you have to use `\nobibliography{my_pubs}` instead of `\nobibliography* \bibliography{my_pubs}` in this way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\nobibliography{my_pubs}

Some text here. My publications:
\begin{itemize}
\item \bibentry{pub1}
\item \bibentry{pub2}
\end{itemize}

Some other text.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted both the list of references and the `\bibentry` tag to work. @karlkoeller's answer didn't work for me, but this did:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\nobibliography*{my_pubs}

Some text here. My publications:
\begin{itemize}
\item \bibentry{pub1}
\item \bibentry{pub2}
\end{itemize}

Some other text.
\bibliography*{my_pubs}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think `\nobibliography*` takes no argument, and `\bibliography` should be unstarred. See the `bibentry` documentation for full details: https://gking.harvard.edu/files/bibentry2.pdf