# Expand citations into bibliographic entries

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, biber, apacite

I am using LaTeX and bibtex for my curriculum, having cite commands for each one of my publications. But, instead of having the bibliographic entries at the end, I want that they get expanded exactly where they are cited.

For that, I was using a Perl scripts, mangling the `.bbl` file into a `.tex` file, and then replacing each citation by the `.bbl` LaTeX code. But this is not just messy, but also difficult to adapt (I just changed the citation type, and now I need to adapt all the code, as the `.bbl` file is generated differently -- I want to use `apacite`, now.).

Is there any module allowing me to do this without using an external tool?

Comment: There is the `bibentry` package (see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142985/35864). `biblatex` has the `\fullcite` command for those sort of things.

Comment: `bibentry` does not work with apacite, it seems.

Comment: Possible. I would have a look if you can post an MWE. `bibentry` is part of the `natbib` family, so maybe it needs a more `natbib`-ish `.bbl` file. Maybe it works if you have `apacite` load `natbib` with the `natbibapa` option.

Comment: MWE with bibtex, bibentry and apacite. https://www.overleaf.com/read/hshxqrpvcxrt

Comment: Any chance you can post a truly minimal example directly in the question? Overleaf links can't replace MWEs (the links might go stale).

Comment: https://gist.github.com/moewew/12657f4181c8558788c678399d9ffa7c is an MWE using `apacite` and `bibentry`.

Comment: Mhh, as it turns out it works only if you don't use `natbibapa`...

Comment: And it seems hyperref doesn't like it, too.

Comment: Yes, just noticed that as well with your MWE. Both `bibentry` and `hyperref` need to manipulate `\bibentry` quite a bit, so clashes like that are not completely surprising. Things would be a lot easier with `biblatex` and its `\fullcite`. `biblatex-apa6` implements 6th edition APA style (which is what `apacite` does as well) and current versions of `biblatex-apa` give you 7th edition APA style.

Comment: Attempting to migrate to biber. Thanks

Comment: Please post the working solution as an answer. That way you can accept it to show the question is resolved and it is easier for people to follow what is question and what is answer.

Comment: Thank you for turning the edit into an answer. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

#### Working version with biber/biblatex

Thanks, @moewe, for pushing me into this. It is lame, because I am the maintainer of `Text::BibTex`, the Perl module `biber` uses.

But nevertheless, this was my first attempt with biber/biblatex, so it took some time to workout how things glue together.

Therefore, I share here a MWE of biber/biblatex if someone finds that useful:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{thing,
  author  = {Someone},
  title   = {Something},
  journal = {Some Journal},
  year    = {2018},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item \fullcite{thing}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}

% pdflatex biblatex-apa
% biber biblatex-apa
% pdflatex biblatex-apa
% pdflatex biblatex-apa
```