# Citations with no bibliograhy at the end in RevTex4-1 (or at least bibliography on a separate page)?

Tags: bibliographies, page-breaking, revtex, bibentry

I am trying to suppress the printing of the bibliography at the end of my RevTex4-1 document, however, I would like to keep the citations in the text.  While invoking the `\nobibliography` command in the bibentry package as described in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31373/citations-with-no-bibliography-at-the-end) works for, say, article style, it does not seem to work for revtex.  If I compile the MWE below with pdflatex, it outputs a multiply defined citation warning and a pdf containing a bibliography!

MWE1:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,noshowpacs,noshowkeys,prb,aps,longbibliography]{revtex4-1}%
\pdfoutput=1
\usepackage{bibentry}

\begin{document}
This is a test \cite{test}.
This is a test \cite{test}.
This is a test \cite{test}.
This is a test \cite{test}.
This is a test \cite{test}.
This is a test \cite{test}.
This is a test \cite{test}.
This is a test \cite{test}.
This is a test \cite{test}.
This is a test \cite{test}.
This is a test \cite{test}.
This is a test \cite{test}.
This is a test \cite{test}.
This is a test \cite{test}.
This is a test \cite{test}.
This is a test \cite{test}.
\bibliographystyle{apsrev}
\nobibliography{testref}
\end{document}
```

The test.bib file is as follows:

```
@book{test,
title="Test book title",
author="Test Author",
year={2014}, 
publisher={TestPubs},
}
```

and the output is:

[image]

Now, while I would prefer to find an answer to the question above (since using bibentry seems to be neater), if there is none, I would be happy to just move the bibliography to a separate page.  However, neither `\newpage` nor `\pagebreak` seem to work. `\clearpage` doesn't preserve the column balance on the page where it's invoke: i.e., this:

MWE2

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,noshowpacs,noshowkeys,prb,aps,longbibliography]{revtex4-1}%
\pdfoutput=1
\usepackage{bibentry}

\begin{document}
This is a test \cite{test}.
This is a test \cite{test}.
This is a test \cite{test}.
This is a test \cite{test}.
This is a test \cite{test}.
This is a test \cite{test}.
This is a test \cite{test}.
This is a test \cite{test}.
This is a test \cite{test}.
This is a test \cite{test}.
This is a test \cite{test}.
This is a test \cite{test}.
This is a test \cite{test}.
This is a test \cite{test}.
This is a test \cite{test}.
This is a test \cite{test}.
\clearpage
\bibliographystyle{apsrev}
\bibliography{testref}
\end{document}
```

results in the following output on the first page:

[image]

Sorry for the long post.

**UPDATE**

As I said in my comment, MWE1 works fine in RevTex4 instead of RevTex4-1 when `\bibliographystyle{apsrev}` line is commented out.  There seems to be an incompatibility between bibentry and apsrev4-1 (the native bibliography style for RevTex4-1), per [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.text.tex/0qNjtWJyxUM/uZ3v4rLXU0UJ).  So, since I don't know a workaround, and since my document looks fine in RevTex4, I'll just use that.

Comment: well Revtex is used as style for many physics journals and you load options in revtex like journal and subjournal. Maybe you Should try \nobibliography again without specify the journal "aps" as option to load. or try \cleardoublepage

Comment: @JaredLo, you are right in that the bibliography options are in the \documentclass.  I deleted the \bibliographystyle line and got all sorts of errors.  However, further research on the Internet seems to indicate that there is an incompatibility between bibentry and apsrev4-1 packages: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.text.tex/0qNjtWJyxUM/uZ3v4rLXU0UJ My MWE1 works fine in RevTex4 when \bibliographystyle line is commented out...  oh well.

Comment: @JaredLo Also, `\cleardoublepage` doesn't seem to have the desired effect, the output looks exactly like the rendering after MWE2...