# Bibliography on separate page in Revtex 4-1

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, page-breaking, citing, revtex

How do I force the bibliography in Revtex 4-1 to appear on a new page?

The default is that it appears immediately after the main body text.

"New Page", "Page Break", "vspace{}" and combinations of these are not working.

The closest information I could find was in this unanswered stackexchange question:
[Citations with no bibliograhy at the end in RevTex4-1 (or at least bibliography on a separate page)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181354/citations-with-no-bibliograhy-at-the-end-in-revtex4-1-or-at-least-bibliography)

**EDIT:**

In response to the comment requesting for an MWE:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\begin{document}
\cite{test,test,test}
\newpage{}\pagebreak{}\newpage{}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\bibliography{C:/Users/library}
\end{document}
```

This works (the bibliography starts on the 2nd page). 
But with:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-1}
```

The bibliography starts on the first page right after the main body text.

Comment: `\newpage` works for me. Can you add a MWE showing why it doesn't work in your case?

Comment: It works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Since block code in the comments isn't well:

Please test the following example and report back the results

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\begin{document}
\cite{companion}
\clearpage
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\end{document}
```

BTW: The journal decides over the overall appearance of articles in their published journals. They will simply revert the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\clearpage` (rather than `\newpage`, `\pagebreak` or `\vspace`).