Update bib reference in tikz image pdf
I have a tikz image that I can't import directly using the standalone package because the text would come out weird and the alignments are all off.
But within this image I need to include a few citation. Is there a way to compile this image into pdf first and update its bib citations later in the main document?

Welcome! In a word: no. If you provide code for a minimal example demonstrating the problem you're having including this in some standard fashion, people may be able to help with that. But your suggested strategy is a non-starter. Sorry.

Sorry but in this case its hard to provide a minimal example in this case because I don't have this issue with tikz usually and I think its related to the template provide. This is a work around that have work but I needed to put citations in my figure.

While it would be easier to compile the TikZ image directly within the document or fix the import issues, here is an approach:
First, write the full main document including all the citations. If there is a citation that you use in the TikZ document but not in the main document you can use \nocite. For example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
The is the main document.
It has some citations such as \cite{book-full} and \cite{inproceedings-full}
and no tech reports\nocite{techreport-minimal}.
\begin{figure}
%% \centering\includegraphics{subtikz-crop}
%% commented out for now
\caption{Citation graph}
\end{figure}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}

Run LaTeX and BibTeX on this file. Then you get a .bbl file with the complete bibliography.
Now make the TikZ figure in a separate file. Paste the full contents of the .bbl file at the end. To make the process a bit easier you can put it inside of a \savebox (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31378/) so the bibliography is available for the TikZ figure but it is not printed (if you don't do this then you need to cut off the page with the bibliography from the pdf with the TikZ figure at some point).
For example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty} % remove page number

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw] (abc) at (0,0) {paper \cite{inproceedings-full}};
\node[rectangle,draw] (def) at (3,0) {paper \cite{techreport-minimal}};
\node[rectangle,draw,rounded corners] (ghi) at (6,0) {paper \cite{book-full}};
\draw[->] (abc) edge (def) (def) edge (ghi);
\end{tikzpicture}
\newsavebox\mytempbib
\savebox\mytempbib{\parbox{\textwidth}{
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\newcommand{\noopsort}[1]{} \newcommand{\printfirst}[2]{#1}
\newcommand{\singleletter}[1]{#1} \newcommand{\switchargs}[2]{#2#1}
\bibitem{book-full}
Donald~E. Knuth.
\newblock {\em Seminumerical Algorithms}, volume~2 of {\em The Art of Computer
  Programming}.
\newblock Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts, second edition, 10~January
  {\noopsort{1973c}}1981.
\newblock This is a full BOOK entry.

\bibitem{inproceedings-full}
Alfred~V. Oaho, Jeffrey~D. Ullman, and Mihalis Yannakakis.
\newblock On notions of information transfer in {VLSI} circuits.
\newblock In Wizard~V. Oz and Mihalis Yannakakis, editors, {\em Proc. Fifteenth
  Annual ACM Symposium on the Theory of Computing}, number~17 in All ACM
  Conferences, pages 133--139, Boston, March 1983. The OX Association for
  Computing Machinery, Academic Press.
\newblock This is a full INPROCEDINGS entry.

\bibitem{techreport-minimal}
Tom Terrific.
\newblock An {$O(n \log n / \! \log\log n)$} sorting algorithm.
\newblock Technical report, Fanstord University, 1988.
\end{thebibliography}
}}
\end{document}

Now crop the figure using pdfcrop in the terminal. For example, when the file is called subtikz.tex:
pdfcrop subtikz.pdf

This will give you a file called subtikz-crop.pdf for which the margins are cut to the contents.
Now you can uncomment the \includegraphics line in the main document and compile again.
Result:


Ingenious. Please point out that this is only needed for BibTeX. If you use Biblatex, you don't have to print the bibliography to use citations. Is there any reason not to just \input the .bbl?

I thought about this but didn't know how to execute it. thank you

@albusSimba Actually, you could do this with Biblatex for the image even if you're not using Biblatex in your document (and can't for e.g. journal/institutional reasons). Since you're only including the image as pre-compiled anyway, all that matters really is that the style of the citations come out uniform. Then you can avoid the need to include the main bibliography etc. Whether this is an advantage or not probably depends on the size of your bibliography file ....

@cfr \input would actually be better because it would reflect changes in the main document and it is cleaner, I didn't think about that.
