# Error with \footnote{\bibentry{foo}} when using beamer

Tags: beamer, footnotes, citing

I am making a beamer presentation and having the following problem:

When I use `\footnote{\bibentry{foo}}` to cite an article, I get the following error message:

```
Undefined Control Sequence}
```

And the footnote does not appear right.  I have used this in other beamer presentation before, though I'm not sure what is going wrong in my case.  I typed

```
\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*
```

before my title slide (which is before `\begin{document}`) and I also typed

```
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\bibliographystyle{amsplain}
\nobibliography{diss_def}
\end{frame}
```

Immediately after `\begin{document}`

Any suggestions on what could be wrong?? Or other suggestions for citing in beamer?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Re: other suggestions: Use `biblatex`. See my answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10547/can-i-use-natbib-in-beamer-but-omit-the-bibliography; for footnote citations, add the `autocite=footnote` package option.

Comment: Please, try providing a minimal example, as what I've tried along your lines works. What is the "undefined control sequence"?

Comment: @lockstep, thanks!  I saw your post on biblatex.  What if I also want to include the name of the journal?

Comment: You could a) switch to an `authortitle` style b) use `\footfullcite` or c) a customized citation command.

Answer (score 1):

What I did to resolve this issue was to simply copy and paste the entry from the .bbl file into \footnote{}