# Hide the bibliography at the end of slides

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use natbib in beamer, but omit the bibliography?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10547/can-i-use-natbib-in-beamer-but-omit-the-bibliography)

At the end of my slides, the bibliography cited are all displayed:

```
...
\bibliographystyle{these}
\bibliography{all}
\end{document}
```

Does anyone know how I can hide them?