# Hiding the references in a letter

Tags: bibliographies, letters

I have written a letter and I want to cite the references of my paper. However, I don't want the reference section to appear at the end of my letter. How can I hide this section?

I have used the `\begin{thebibliography}` and `\bibitem` for the references and I am citing them by `\cite{marcam2(alfa)}`.

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{marcam2(alfa)}
M. Abramowitz and I. A. Stegun, {\it Handbook of mathematical functions with formulas, graphs, and mathematical tables}. U. S. Department of Commerce, 1972.
\bibitem{choi(2u)}
H. Bolcskei, R. U. Nabar, O. Oyman and A. J. Paulraj, `` Capacity scaling laws in MIMO relay networks, " {\it IEEE Trans. Wireless Commun}., vol. 5, no. 6, pp. 1433-1444, June 2006.
\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: Assuming the references are on a separate page, could you simply delete that page from the pdf file?

Comment: It is feasible. Take a look at this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10548/27635

Comment: @karlkoeller - I'm not sure if the answer you've provided a link to is useful for the OP's current situation: the answer assumes that the bibliography is created dynamically via BibTeX (or biblatex), whereas the OP seems to have a hand-coded `thebibliography` environment.

Comment: @Mico, I've tried it with a handmade `thebibliography` and it works for me

Comment: I've used this for similar purposes: put your `thebibliograpy` environment in a separate file (if it is not in one already). Let's say it's calles `mypaper.bbl` Then you can put `\setbox0=\vbox{\input mypapaer.bbl}". Then the items are read and typeset and their labels are defined, but nothing is printed, all being stored away in `\box0`, which you should then never use.

Comment: You could change the color to white, or stick it into a \savebox.

Comment: Thank you all friends. The answer of my firend @karlkoeller worked for me.